# Multilanguage resume import from LinkedIn in Careers 2.0

Tags: support, jobs

I've just been given an invite to Careers 2.0 and it looks awesome! I tried to import my LinkedIn resume (which is in two languages) but I could not find a way to import the English version: the system just imports the Italian version of the resume.

I double checked but I could not find a way to specify which language to import (or a way to import them both). Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have the same problem.. I hope they resolve this.